# PushBots : How to show notifications in layout?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushbots

I am new to stack overflow.

I am developing an android app which uses PushBots for push notifications. I am all ready with PushBots enabled in my app. I am even able to send push notifications. But I want to store the notification text and show them inside the app not just the notification bar. Please help me resolve the issue. Pardon me if my language is incorrect.

Thank you.

Receiver class :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class customPushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "customPushReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);
        // Handle Push Message when opened
        if (action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_OPENED)) {
            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>)  intent.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_OPEN);                intent.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_OPEN);
        Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));
        // Start activity if not active
        // set the value of local variable "active" in onStart()/onStop() in MainActivity
        // to check for MainActivity status
        if(!MainActivity.isActive()){
            Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launch.setClass(Pushbots.getInstance().appContext, MainActivity.class);
            launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Pushbots.getInstance().appContext.startActivity(launch);
        }
        // Handle Push Message when received
        }else if(action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE)){
            HashMap<?, ?> Pushdata = (HashMap<?, ?>)  intent.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE);
            Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + Pushdata.get("message"));
        }
    }
}
```

Pushbots Initialize:

```
Pushbots.getInstance().regID();
```

These are some recent lines in Log :

07-14 23:42:42.752: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2491): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

07-14 23:42:42.752: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2491): GCM IntentService class: com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService

07-14 23:42:42.752: V/PBGCMBaseIntentService(2491): Acquiring wakelock

07-14 23:42:42.760: I/PBGCMIntentService(2491): Received a Notification.

07-14 23:42:42.760: D/PBGenerateNotification(2491): notification will be canceled from status bar when it is clicked by the user.

07-14 23:42:42.764: D/PBRequestTask(2491): PUT Request : https://api.pushbots.com/stats

07-14 23:42:42.780: V/PBGCMBaseIntentService(2491): Releasing wakelock

07-14 23:42:49.888: D/PB(2491): PushBots Request successful!

07-14 23:43:51.532: D/PBMsgReceiver(2491): No intent receiver set, not sending com.pushbots.MSG_OPENED

07-14 23:43:51.532: D/PBRequestTask(2491): PUT Request : https://api.pushbots.com/stats

07-14 23:43:51.812: D/PB(2491): PushBots Request successful!

Comment: store the received data in local database

Comment: Thanks. But i dont know how to store notifications sent from Pushbots in local databse.

Comment: please post your notification code

Comment: notification will not be stored in database but the data coming in the notification will be stored

Comment: Please post the relevant display/integration code.

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to fetch the data from the notifications. I just want to get the notification text in a string.

Comment: in pushbots website it is there how to handle the received data in broadcastreciever

Comment: @madhu would you please tell me how to fetch the notification text. I followed what's given on Pushbots site. But didn't work. Thank you for help.

Comment: are you getting the message in log

Comment: @madhu no.not showing message in log

Comment: @madhu Thank you for your help. It worked ! I didn't read log correctly.